# Shortening large numbers to improve readability

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting, string-formatting

Is there a generic/better way to shorten larger numbers?
Numbers > 1000 should to shortened to two decimal places and appended a 'k' e.g. 1543 should become 1.54k, while 1504 should be shortened to 1.5k and 1007 shortened to 1k.

The same should be done for numbers > 1000000, they should get M appended.
Example: 5426849 should be shortened to 5.42M (wouldn't mind 5.43M), 5403258 shortened to 5.4M
and 5001485 shortened to 5M.

Currently I have this:

```
std::string letter(_sum > 1000000 ? "M" : _sum > 1000 ? "k" : "");
float displayValue(_sum > 1000000 ? _sum/1000000 : _sum > 1000 ? _sum/1000 : _sum);
printf("%.2g%s", displayValue, letter);
```

Comment: "while 1054 should be shortened to 1.5k" There has to be a typo somewhere ;)

Comment: I wrote code for this a couple of years ago but it was (*shudder*) in MFC and properly grouped digits using Windows-specific locale awareness APIs. I'll see if I can dig it out and remove the cruft to make it more "standard C++".

Comment: I wouldn't call this "shortening numbers".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499219/560648

Comment: Ahh! Excellent @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Marking as duplicate and voting to close.

Comment: @Nik I don't think the questions duplicate one another.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps not precisely, but close enough, at least imho.